# Make a heirarchical tree component which has Employee and Manger relation in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, treeview

I have a Js object which has both manager IDs and employee IDs, I want to create a ReactJs Tree component that shows all the managers and their employees.
So if I click on a manager it should expand and show all the employees reporting to him/her.
How can I do it using Material UI Tree view or any other way?

The object looks like:

```
const empMangerData= [{emp_id: 'EMP001', manager_id: ''},
 {emp_id: 'EMP002', manager_id: 'EMP001'},
 {emp_id: 'EMP003', manager_id: 'EMP001'},
 {emp_id: 'EMP004', manager_id: 'EMP002'},
 {emp_id: 'EMP005', manager_id: 'EMP002'}
 {…}]
```

This is an example of what I want

[image: This is an example of what I want]

Comment: We need to see the JS object, or an example of one also

Comment: @AdamThomas, I have updated the question with a sample object.

Answer (score 1):

refer [material-ui treeview](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-treeview-select-child-nodes-on-root-node-select-1j9ldu)

I have used a similar data to create a material-ui tree.